# At least $P(m, n - 1) = {{m!}\over{(m - n+1)!}}$ surjective functions from $[m]$ to $[n]$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

How do I see that there are at least$$P(m, n - 1) = {{m!}\over{(m - n+1)!}}$$surjective functions from $[m]$ to $[n]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Pick $n-1$ objects in order from $m$. Send them via $f$ to $1,2,3,..,n-1$. Send all the remaining object to $n$.

In how many ways can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: choose single elements to map to each of $1, 2, \ldots, n-1$, and map everything else to $n$.